# Create tags by selector (needs library)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some selectors:

- `.div1`
- `.div1>div`
- `.div1>div:nth-child(3)`
- `.div2>div:nth-child(3)`

and the following html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="div1">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any JS library, that can create structure of tags  for not found selectors?

Or, is there any JS template engine what works with common selectors?

I need something like this:

`var newTag = $('.div2>div:nth-child(3)', document.body)`

new html structure:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="div1">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div><!--return this element-->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### (jQuery style is not important)

Comment: The problem with this is that selectors like `.div2>div:nth-child(3)` are ambiguous in terms of *creating* HTML based on the selector. The generator would not know what type the 1st and 2nd children of the second `<div>` should be. Whilst you've used `<div>`s in your example, there's no rule for that to be the case.

Comment: @Matt , for example ZenCoding create by default ```div```. Is there something like ZenCoding?

Comment: In which case, why can't you use ZenCoding?

Comment: First of all - I don't see any where js library for Zen (only CodeMirror plugin). Also Zen creates nodes without checking that they exists.

Comment: Use the ZenCoding (now emmet) library directly; just include `/lib/emmet.js` using your favourite module-loading library, then [`expandAbbreviation()`](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/28914ae936e4becad0847d9c7635cd2b71efcddb/lib/emmet.js#L67-82) is the function you need. Admittedly, you'd have to get around the node checking ability though.